# Replace FOR to add all values in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using Javascript, and I have an array like this:

```
counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 0 },
      { id: 2, value: 10 },
      { id: 3, value: 5 },
      { id: 4, value: 3 }
    ]
```

I want to get a variable total, with the sum of every value field in the counters array. Right now I'm doing:

```
Total() {
    let total = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
      total += counters[i].value;
    }
    return total;   
}
```

Even if that works, I know that there's a better way. I tried `reduce` method, but I couldn't get what I need. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You could add the [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) value with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var object = { counters: [{ id: 1, value: 0 }, { id: 2, value: 10 }, { id: 3, value: 5 }, { id: 4, value: 3 }] },
    sum = object.counters.reduce((s, { value }) => s + value, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const  counters = [
       { id: 1, value: 0 },
       { id: 2, value: 10 },
       { id: 3, value: 5 },
       { id: 4, value: 3 }
     ]
     
 const total = counters.map(x => x.value).reduce((a,c) => a +c)
 
 console.log(total)
```

`map` your array to represent only the `value` property and use `reduce`

```
 const total = counters.map(x => x.value).reduce((a,c) => a + c)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with reduce, simply pass in a default value of 0:

```js
counters = [
       { id: 1, value: 0 },
       { id: 2, value: 10 },
       { id: 3, value: 5 },
       { id: 4, value: 3 }
     ]
     
total = counters.reduce((accumulator, counter) => accumulator + counter.value, 0);

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way is to use reduce method
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
 ;)

`const total = counters.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.value, 0);`